# None of the email sent in my magento website?

Tags: magento-1.9

I am using in magento 1.9 in my website. I created account, reset password, order mail, invoice mail etc none of the mail send to the customer. I don't know the what's the problem. can you please any one suggest what is the problem??

Comment: Is your cron setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Emails are sent on an automated script now so you need to set it up by adding the cron.php to your crontab schedule. We tend to run ours every 5 minutes. You can see if emails are queued up to be sent by looking in the cron_email_queue table.

Comment: Already i have a cron.php file in my root folder

Comment: But you still need to add it to your cron schedule. It will not run automatically.

Comment: can you please tell me how to run automatically

Comment: do you have ssh access to the server?

Comment: No but tell me how i will contact to my server person

Comment: Your server person should already know how. They need to add cron.php located in your public folder to the crontab to run every 5 minutes.

Comment: ok thanks after update cron job mail will work???

Answer (score 2):

Have you enable the email communication in admin panel??

If not Navigate to

> admin > system > configuration > system > mail sending settings > Disable email communication

to no.

Comment: it's no only...